# Grails How to show a different link name in a form

Tags: grails

In my domain i have a one to many relationship with Inventory and Inventory Item. This is the snippet from the gsp. It shows each inventory item assigned to a specific inventory.

```
<g:if test="${inventoryInstance?.inventoryItem}">
    <li class="fieldcontain">
        <span id="inventoryItem-label" class="property-label"><g:message code="inventory.inventoryItem.label" default="Inventory Item" /></span>            
            <g:each in="${inventoryInstance.inventoryItem}" var="i">
                <span class="property-value" aria-labelledby="inventoryItem-label">
                   <g:link controller="inventoryItem" 
                           action="show" 
                           id="${i.id}">${i?.encodeAsHTML()}
                   </g:link>
                </span>
            </g:each>       
    </li>
</g:if>
```

Problem is the links shown is package.InventoryItem: 1

how do you change it to the InventoryItem's name ( i have a name row in my database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
${i.name?.encodeAsHTML()}
```

If `i` is null then you would get a NPE right when you use `i.id`. Moreover, you should not be iterating over a Collection of `inventoryItems` expecting it has an empty item. :)

Have a look at the [second example](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/ref/Tags/link.html) for the answer.

If you want `i` to return the `name` by default then you have to override `toString()` which I  would not do.